# Why does the str.isdigit always output the opposite result

Tags: python

```py
def is_valid_zip(zip_code):
    """Returns whether the input string is a valid (5 digit) zip code
    """
    if (len(zip_code) == 5) and (str.isnumeric == True):
        return True
    else : 
        return False
```

Comment: What do you think about `str.isnumeric` will do?

Answer (score 1):

A few point to discuss. Regarding your condition:

```py
str.isnumeric == True
```

That thing on the left side is the function itself, *not* a call to the function giving a result, the latter would be `some_string.isnumeric()`.

The chances of the *function* object being equal to true are somewhere between zero and a very, *very* small number :-)

It's also redundant to compare boolean values against boolean constants since the result of the comparison is just another boolean value. Where do you stop in that case? For example:

```py
(((some_bool_value == True) == True) == True) != False ...
```

Another point, the code form `if cond then return true else return false` can be replaced with the much less verbose `return cond`.

And also keep in mind that `isnumeric()` allows other things than raw digits, like `¾`. If you just want the digits, you're probably better off with another method. You may be tempted to instead use `isdigit()`, but even *that* allows other things than just what most would consider "normal" digits, such as allowing `"90²10"` as a postal code, presumably the much trendier part of Beverly Hills :-).

If you *only* wanted the raw digits `0-9` (which is probably the case with US postal codes like you seem to be targeting), neither `isnumeric()` nor `isdigit()` is really suitable.

---

An implementation of the function, taking all that into account, could be as follows:

```py
def is_valid_zip(zip_code):
    if len(zip_code) != 5:
        return False
    return all([x in "1234567890" for x in zip_code])
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it should be `str.isnumeric() == True` as that's calling the isnumeric function. Second of all you should be really using `str.isdigit()`.

**str.isnumeric()**
In Python, decimal characters (like: 0, 1, 2..), digits (like: subscript, superscript), and characters having Unicode numeric value property (like: fraction, roman numerals, currency numerators) are all considered numeric characters. Therefore even japanese character for 1, 2 and 3 would pass this check.

**str.isdigit()**
On the other hand isdigit() will only return True if all characters in a string are digits. If not, it returns False.

source: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/isdigit

Comment: Just keep in mind that "isdigit()" also allows things like `90²10`, which you probably want to avoid in a postal code. It's not as *bad* as `isnumeric()` but it's still not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

it should be `zip_code.isnumeric()` not `str.isnumeric`

Also, why don't you use regex:

```
import re
RE_ZIP_CODE = re.compile(r'^[0-9]{5}$')  # or r'^\d{5}$' for all digit characters

def is_valid_zip(zip_code):
    
    return RE_ZIP_CODE.search(zip_code) is not None
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
def is_valid_zip(zip_code):
    """Returns whether the input string is a valid (5 digit) zip code
    """
    if len(zip_code) == 5 and zip_code.isnumeric():
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(is_valid_zip("98909"))
```